# creating win/loss records using group by and count

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

im trying to create a 3 field query result, market, wins, and losses.  The win and loss result is based on a boolean field, just counting number of records either true or false,  I've created 3 seperate queries and have gotten them to give me results I want, just having issues combining them in google big query, getting error "Scalar subquery produced more than one element", not really understanding that statement,   Thank you

```
select market, count(*)TotalGamesPLayed, 

(select count(*)
from `bigquery-public-data.ncaa_basketball.mbb_teams_games_sr` 
  WHERE
    season IN (2017)
    AND conf_name IN ("Big Ten") and win = true 
    group by season, market
    order by market asc)win,

    (select count(*)
from `bigquery-public-data.ncaa_basketball.mbb_teams_games_sr` 
  WHERE
    season IN (2017)
    AND conf_name IN ("Big Ten") and win = false 
    group by season, market
    order by market asc)loss,
    from `bigquery-public-data.ncaa_basketball.mbb_teams_games_sr` 
  WHERE
    season IN (2017)
    AND conf_name IN ("Big Ten") 
    group by market
    order by market asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are attempting to run subqueries in `SELECT` cause which usually requires correlating with outer query for a return of single value. Instead, join the subqueries as derived tables in `FROM`|and `JOIN` clauses. However, since both queries share same sources, run one conditional aggregate query where `WHERE` conditions are moved to `CASE` statements.

```
select market,
       count(*) as total_games,
       sum(case 
                when win = true 
                then 1
                else 0
           end) as win,
       sum(case 
                when win = false
                then 1
                else 0
           end) as loss
from `bigquery-public-data.ncaa_basketball.mbb_teams_games_sr`
where season = 2017 
  and conf_name = 'Big Ten'
group by market
order by market asc
```

Also, in some databases you can even bypass `CASE` and sum the logical conditions:

```
 sum(win = true) as win,
 sum(win = false) as loss
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  market, 
  COUNT(*) AS TotalGamesPLayed, 
  COUNTIF(win) AS win, 
  COUNTIF(NOT win) AS loss 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.ncaa_basketball.mbb_teams_games_sr` 
WHERE season IN (2017)
AND conf_name IN ("Big Ten") 
GROUP BY market
ORDER BY market ASC
```

Comment: glad it worked for you. consider also voting up the answer - this is important here on SO